# How to use Thread.sleep() in this example in android

Tags: android, thread-sleep

I have some example code on main thread:

```
userButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            simpleMessage.setText("Msg1");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            simpleMessage.setText("Msg2");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            simpleMessage.setText("Msg3");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that it only updates text to "Msg3" after certain amount of time. Why is that happening and how to make it update at every message?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep time ? May be still its happening too quickly ?

Comment: "Why is that happening" -- because you are tying up the main application thread, preventing it from updating the screen, courtesy of your `Thread.sleep()` calls. "how to make it update at every message?" -- you will need to give control back to the main application thread and arrange to get control again later on to update your `TextView`. For example, you could use `postDelayed()` and a `Runnable`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed